# How can I add a video using the video_tag helper on my sign_in devise page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I'm having an issue to display a video on my `sign_in` page (I use devise in my rails app).

I tried to setup the `video_tag` helper but it doesn't seem to work. Here my code:

In `application.rb`:

```
module PONG
  class Application < Rails::Application
    config.assets.paths << "#{Rails.root}/app/assets/videos"
    
    config.generators do |generate|
      generate.assets false
      generate.helper false
      generate.test_framework :test_unit, fixture: false
    end
    # Initialize configuration defaults for originally generated Rails version.
    config.load_defaults 6.0
    config.time_zone = "Paris"
  end
end
```

In `new.html.erb`:

```
<%= video_tag 'login-video.mp4', autoplay: :autoplay, loop: :loop, muted: :muted %>
```

I also created a `videos` folder in my `assets` folder containing the `login-video.mp4`.

When I try to reach this page, I get the following error message:

```
Sprockets::Rails::Helper::AssetNotPrecompiled in Devise::Sessions#new
```

In my `development.rb`, my `config.assets.debug` is well set to false: `config.assets.debug = false`

Help please!

Comment: Did you restart your local server after adding `config.assets.paths << "#{Rails.root}/app/assets/videos"` ?

Comment: Yes I did and it didn't change anything :/

Comment: Well I see you found a solution! Regards from a fellow Le Wagoner :)

Comment: Small world haha :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I figured it out. I added this line to my `development.rb`:

```
  config.assets.check_precompiled_asset = false
```

Now, it works perfectly!